# Is this a sensible pattern for reusing a C++11 lambda within a calling function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a lambda that I wish to use more than once, but I want it to operate on at least one different (capture) variable the second time around. Is this approach - using a captured pointer ref inside the lambda that is redirected in the calling code to a different variable - a normal/sensible way to do it? Or should I be using a separate mechanism, or a different approach altogether?

```
MyStruct ms1;
MyStruct* pActiveMyStruct = &ms1;
auto lambda = [&]( const Foo& foo, u32 index )
{
    pActiveMyStruct->sScore = foo.m_Score;
    pActiveMyStruct->DoSomethingWith( index );
};
pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda );

MyStruct ms2;
pActiveMyStruct = &ms2;
pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda );
```

Comment: Yes, it seems fine, why not?

Comment: try to avoid generalized captures [&] (often you capture more than you actually want). also pointers to local variables can get you into trouble quite fast.

Comment: Why do you insist on accessing struct methods via pointer?

Comment: @Killzone Kid - I don't really understand the question.

Comment: @Kaitain You seem to go an extra step to make a pointer to your struct and and then use it to access struct methods, while you can do this without needing the pointer with dot `.` operator alone

Comment: How are you going to reassign a reference?

Answer (score 5):

The functional-style approach would be to use a closure:

```
MyStruct ms1, ms2;
auto makeLambda = [](MyStruct& ms) {
    return [&ms](const Foo& foo, u32 index) {
        ms.sScore = foo.m_Score;
        ms.DoSomethingWith(index);
    };
};

pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn(makeLambda(ms1));
pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn(makeLambda(ms2));
```

Comment: Yes, that does seem more elegant, although presumably has higher runtime overhead.

Comment: Potentially, though most compilers are very good at optimizing lambdas.  GCC optimizes this trivial example even at `-O1`: https://godbolt.org/g/qq2V9d

Answer (score 1):

I think the following options are better than using a reference to a pointer.

#### Option 1

Use a reference to the `MyStruct` object itself instead of a reference to the pointer.

```
MyStruct ms1;
auto lambda = [&ms1]( const Foo& foo, u32 index )
{
    ms1.sScore = foo.m_Score;
    ms1.DoSomethingWith( index );
};

pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda );

MyStruct ms2;
ms1 = ms2;
pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda );
```

#### Option 2

Pass the `MyStruct` object to the lambda function.

```
auto lambda = [&ms1]( const Foo& foo, u32 index, MyStruct& ms )
{
    ms.sScore = foo.m_Score;
    ms.DoSomethingWith( index );
};
```

To be able to do that, `pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn` must have access to the `MyStruct` object. You can do that couple of ways.

1. Store the `MyStruct` object in `pProcessor` and use it in the implementation of `ApplyLambdaOn`.

   ```
   pProcessor->setData(ms1);
   pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda );

   MyStruct ms2;
   pProcessor->setData(ms2);
   pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda );
   ```
2. Pass the `MyStruct` object to `ApplyLambdaOn` as another argument.

   ```
   pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda, ms1 );

   MyStruct ms2;
   pProcessor->ApplyLambdaOn( lambda, ms2 );
   ```

Comment: Somehow, I think I would use option 2, but with std::bind

Comment: @JamesPoag, I encourage you to formulate an answer and post it.